# Calculating how much area of an ellipsis is covered by a certain pixel in Python

Tags: python

I am working with Python and currently trying to figure out the following: If I place an ellipsis of which the semi-axes, the centre's location and the orientation are known, on a pixel map, and the ellipsis is large enough to cover multiple pixels, how do I figure out which pixel covers which percentage of the total area of the ellipsis? As an example, let's take a map of 10*10 pixels (i.e. interval of [0,9]) and an ellipsis with the centre at (6.5, 6.5), semi-axes of (0.5, 1.5) and an orientation angle of 30° between the horizontal and the semi-major axis. I have honestly no idea, so any help is appreciated.

edit: To clarify, the pixels (or cells) have an area. I know the area of the ellipsis, its position and its orientation, and I want to find out how much of its area is located within pixel 1, how much it is within pixel 2 etc.

Comment: Sounds more like a Math problem than a programming problem. How about painting the ellipse and then counting the coloured pixels?

Comment: What do you mean by "which pixel covers which percentage of the total area of the ellipsis"? Do pixel have area?

Comment: @ThomasWeller it is not just about counting the pixels themselves, it is basically about "weighting" them.

Comment: @jimifiki yes they do, albeit I guess the more accurate term here would be cells. If an ellipsis covers, say, three pixels, and and 50% of the area of the ellipsis is on one pixel, 20% on another one and 30% on the last one, how can I find that out?

Comment: What about the space between pixels? What about subpixels? Different screens have different pixel layouts (rectangular, triangular, some have 2 blue subpixels).

Comment: @ThomasWeller no space between pixels, no subpixels. This is about a known camera model (albeit of course idealised with the former assumption) using quadratic pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Following [the equation of an elipse](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/joma/Volume8/Kalman/General.html)

[image]

The easiest way to find which pixels from your mesh are inside and which are out would be to assign `(x, y, alpha)` for each pixel in the above equation.

If the result `<=1`, the pixel is inside. Otherwise, it is outside.

You can count the pixels.

Comment: It's not just about finding out which pixels are inside or outside; each pixel (or cell) has an area, and I need to know how much area of the ellipsis overlaps with which pixels.

Comment: @DerAstrophysiker: so basically you also want to have anti-aliasing as well

Comment: you want to know per pixel, how much area of it is covered by the elipsis?

Comment: @Gulzar that's pretty much it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I don't know what that is supposed to mean in this context, but I think the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

This is math problem. Try math.exchange rather than stackoverflow.

I suggest you to transform the plane: translation to get the center in the middle, rotation to get the ellipsis's axes on the x-y ones and dilatation on x to get a circle. And then work with a circle on rhombus tiles.

Your problem won't be less or more tractable in the new formulation but the math and code you have to work on will be slightly lighter.